# Send data to child component from partent after an ajax call in react js

Tags: reactjs, components, state

I have a TextInput react component with

```
getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
        value : ""
    }
},

getInitialState: function () {
    return {
       value: this.props.value
    }
}
```

and it generates a simple `<input type="text" value={this.state.value}>`. I'm using this component on many other components, where I'm sending default data (`<InputText value="some string"/>`)

But when I'm trying to send to it data from server it doesn't work.

E.G:I have a Form component

```
 getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
        workingData : {}
    }
},

getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        workingData: this.props.workingData
    }
},

componentDidMount: function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'api/someFile.php',
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({workingData: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
},
```

The workingData is now an object like {a: 'a', b: 'b'}

In render:

```
<TextInput  ref="myInput"
        value={this.state.workingData.someValueFromObj}
```

If in `<InputText />` component I'm changing in render from this.state.value to this.props.value, this is working.

Also, if I'm not getting data from server, and I declare an object inside `<Form />` also is working perfect with this.state.value in InputText.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Could this be a scoping issue in the success callback of your ajax call? Try declaring something like `var that = this` above your ajax call. Then change `this.setState...` to `that.setState...` Not sure if this will solve it but that's where I would start

Comment: @pmilla1606 is exactly correct. You cannot use `this` like you are doing inside an Ajax handler

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. After a lot of console.log, I saw how is this working. So first is rendering the Form component, after this the inputText component (and it displayed a console.log from getInitialState), and after this the ajax call is executed, Form is rendering again, InputText again, but this time I don't have the console.log from getInitialState.   I've found a solution, but I don't like it: in inputText form i have a method setValue that make setState, and when ajax success I'm calling that method for my InputText component.